# Call unmanaged fastcall C function by address in C#

Tags: c#, c, .net, pointers, dll

I'm injecting my C# dll into an unmanaged process written in C. How would I go about calling a function in this process? I know the address of the function and the function signature. The function uses `fastcall` calling convention. I'm not sure if this complicates things.

I have tried using delegates like so:

```
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.FastCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public delegate IntPtr _PrintText(string msg, int color);
```

Which raises a warning about `FastCall` not being supported.

Here's a more complete, simple example of what I've tried:

C++ function:

```
void __fastcall PrintText (wchar_t * wMessage, int nColor)
Address: 0x31E3A0
```

C# code:

```
public class Example
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.FastCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public delegate IntPtr _PrintText(string msg, int color);

    public static int EntryPoint(string pwzArgument)
    {
        var ptr = new IntPtr(0x31E3A0);
        _PrintText MyPrint = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<_PrintText>(ptr);
        MyPrint("TESTING", 0);
    }
}
```

How do I properly define and call a `FastCall` C function using C#?

Comment: You need also `CharSet.Unicode` to match that C++ signature.